# How to prevent singleton form being destroyed?

Tags: android, singleton, android-lifecycle

In my app I have singleton class which holds all data about user's current workout. The data is constantly updated as user progresses with his workout. The problem is that usually after several minutes android os terminates my singleton and all data is lost. How could I tell android os to not terminate my singleton or at least decrease the chance of it happening?

```
public class WorkoutManager{
    private static WorkoutManager instance;

    private WorkoutManager() {}

    private ArrayList<Workout> workouts = new ArrayList<>();

    public static WorkoutManager getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new WorkoutManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public ArrayList<Workout> getWorkouts(){
        return workouts;
    }

    public Workout getWorkout(int index){
        return workouts.get(index);
    }

    public void setWorkouts(ArrayList<Workout> workouts){
        this.workouts = workouts;
    }

    public void addWorkout(Workout workout){
        workouts.add(workout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Android is not terminating your singleton, it is terminating your app. If you want your data to be persistent write it to a DB..

Comment: create your class under application class,then it will persist during your app lifecycle

Comment: My singleton is getting updated every second writing all data every second to DB wouldn't be good solution.

Comment: Why would that not be a good solution? Do you like losing all your data every time?

Comment: So if I replace public class WorkoutManager{ with public class WorkoutManager extends Application{, my singleton will be alive as long as app is alive?